# How to manually(without keybindings) search a symbol in a source code using coc-clangd/coc-nvim?

Tags: c++, c, neovim, coc.nvim, clangd

I use neovim and coc-clangd for C/C++ programming. Every thing is ok and i can jump through definitions and search references of a symbol in all of my project files by holding the cursor on the symbol and use the `gr` keybinding for calling the `jumpReferences` action.

i want to know that is there any option to search a symbol by simply typing it and not with `gr` key binding in coc-clangd?

actually i can do this job using cscope by bellow command:

`:cs find global <symbol-name>`

but it would be much better using coc-clangd, because the indexing procedure is more simple. so i searched and found [this link](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/release/doc/coc.txt) and in there i found `jumpReferences` coc action. i played so much with this action. for example i have run bellow command:

`:call CocAction('jumpReferences', <symbol-name>)`

this does not cause any error but ignores `<symbol-name>` and just gives the list of references to the symbol under the cursor.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer after more searching. Actually I have seen the answer to my question in the [coc.nvim repository](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) but to figure it out I had to read it more carefully.

based on the [feature list of clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/features.html#navigation), searching symbols in the scope of the whole project is available since `clangd-10`. (after understanding this fact) I found bellow lines in the vim [sample configuration for coc.nvim plugin](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim):

```
" Search workspace symbols.
nnoremap <silent><nowait> <space>s  :<C-u>CocList -I symbols<cr>
```

so by we can search a symbol in a project just by hitting `<space>s` and type the symbol name in the openning interactive buffer.

Note: the list of symbols that coc-clangd finds is less than that of cscope. I actually think that this is not meaning that coc-clangd is not complete. Actually, coc-clangd works well. for example, consider the case of symbol `io_delay` in the linux kernel. this symbol is a function and coc.nvim/coc-clangd finds all of its references in the projct but there are some places where it is used like bellow:

```
.io_delay = xen_io_delay,
```

and clangd does not see these usages but cscope finds them. In this situation as i know the `io_delay` is not a function and the fact that clangd does not see it is not a drawback for it and actually I think it works well. I think(I don't know exactly) cscope indexing sometimes works like the searching in vim and because the word `io_delay` is used in this situation cscope sees this usage of `io_delay`.(this was what i thought about the reason of this situation so i would be happy if someone expert explains it more and clarify it for everyone.)